# How can I rotate PDF files by 90° in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

Sometimes I have PDF files that have pages shown horizontally. I usually use Google Chrome to open PDF files, and I was wondering is there anyway to "turn" the file by 90 degrees so that I can read it in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of Chrome 17 you can right-click on the PDF and choose "Rotate clockwise" or "Rotate counterclockwise".

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, with Chrome, you cant.  You can read the article about it [here](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/06/bringing-improved-pdf-support-to-google.html).  You will have to open it in another browser, or within Acrobat.

In IE, for example, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>-</kbd> to rotate a PDF in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ctrl+]` to Rotate the `.pdf` file Clockwise
and
Use `ctrl+[` to Rotate the `.pdf` file AntiClockwise

Answer (score 0):

You can click on `Rotate clockwise`.

These also seem to work:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>}</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

<  Everything I'm about to say applies to a PDF opened with google classroom (the link actually says google docs). I googled "pdf example" and tested the above methods on that and they seemed to work. The two methods do appear different: [browser version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMzYz.png) [classroom/doc version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esvPP.png) >

I'm on chrome as we (I) speak. Right-clicking the pdf doesn't even open up a tab, let alone give an option to rotate it. As for the ctrl {,},[, or ] commands, none of them work. At least of my keyboard, "[" and "{" are the same key. (  same for "}" and "]"      )
I'm 90% certain whatever the solution is will be some outside software
( hopefully just an extension ).

Answer (score -1):

For Google Chrome - you can right click and rotate it.  That is temporary, but if you want to make it permanent.  After you Rotate it, hit the download button and it will ask you if you want to download the original or the edited.  Download the edited and it is rotated permanently in that download.